# Charts not being deleted by Chartobject.Delete?

Tags: vba, charts, pivot-table

I have a macro that creates a pivot table and then creates a chart based on the pivot. I want to delete the old pivot table and chart, before replacing them with the new data.

I can get red of the pivot table with `Cells.Delete`.

According to what I found online I should be able to get rid of the chart with `ChartObjects.Delete`.

However this doesn't seem to work. Also `ChartObjects.Count` returns 0.

I know that a simple workaround would be to delete the entire sheet and then just add a new one but I would like to avoid that.

Any Ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: When you create the chart give it a name and use that as a reference for the delete. Store the reference qualified with the appropriate workbook+sheet reference in a variable and delete by reference to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to first get the name and delete every chartObjects in active sheet. Count should return other than 0 though.

```
Sub deleteChartObjects()

Dim chartName As String
Dim cht As ChartObject

For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    chartName = cht.Name
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName)
    cht.Delete
Next

End Sub
```